# Do I need a Japan visa?

Tags: visas, japan, indian-citizens, layovers

I am an Indian passport holder. I am planning to travel from Delhi to Vancouver, Canada with Japan Airlines and there is a layover of 11 hours in Narita, Tokyo. So do I need any kind of visa from Japan for staying such long hours ?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need a Visa. Your nationality does not matter also. People from all nationalities can transit if they do not intend to leave the airport for activities outside the transit areas in the airport

According to the [Japan Embassy in India](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html), you can obtain a Transit Visa if you intend to leave the transit area for certain activities.